# Xcode build phase to copy app file to the Applications directory?

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, build-process

I'm using Xcode 6 to create Mac OS X applications, and I'd like to create a final build phase that copies the App file to the Applications directory. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out - I had to add a Copy Files phase to the end of the Build Phases.

In this phase, I specify Absolute Path: /Applications, and I dragged the product (.app) file to the files list.